# How to troubleshoot power-supply issues?

Tags: windows-7, power-supply, reboot, desktop-computer

I have a PC running Windows 7 that sometimes reboots randomly.
The Event View-er shows the following

Date:          6/26/2016 5:13:51 PM

Event ID:      41

Task Category: (63)

Level:         Critical

Keywords:      (2)

User:          SYSTEM

Computer:      ComputerName

Description:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

Event Xml:

```
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />

<EventID>41</EventID>

<Version>2</Version>

<Level>1</Level>

<Task>63</Task>

<Opcode>0</Opcode>

<Keywords>0x8000000000000002</Keywords>

<TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-06-26T14:13:51.192411800Z" />

<EventRecordID>342359</EventRecordID>

<Correlation />

<Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />

<Channel>System</Channel>

<Computer>ComputerName</Computer>

<Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
```

```
<Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data>

<Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data>

<Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data>

<Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data>

<Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data>

<Data Name="SleepInProgress">false</Data>

<Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">131114239970732138</Data>
```

I am in the process of ruling out the software problems, but I don't know how to troubleshoot power-supply issues.

Comment: Is the system overclocked? Particularly CPU overclocking can cause all kinds of weird problems.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has provided a KB article about your sporadic reboots:

**Windows Kernel event ID 41 error "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first"**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504

Your important part is Scenario 3:

*The system randomly restarts and no Stop error BugcheckCode is listed, or the computer is completely unresponsive (hard hang)*

> To check whether this scenario is occurring, press the CAPS LOCK key
>   on the keyboard. When you do this, if the CAPS LOCK light on the
>   keyboard does not change when you press the CAPS LOCK key, the
>   computer may be completely unresponsive (hard hang).
>
> This scenario usually indicates a problem with the hardware. To help
>   isolate the problem, check the following items:

1. **Overclocking**: Disable overclocking to see whether the issue occurs when the system is run at the correct speed.
2. **Check the memory**: Verify the memory by using a memory checker. Verify that each memory chip is the same speed and that it is configured correctly in the system.
3. **Power supply**: Make sure that the power supply has enough wattage to appropriately handle the installed devices. If you added memory, installed a newer processor, installed additional drives, or added external devices, such devices can require more energy than the current power supply can provide consistently.
4. **Overheating**: Check whether the system is overheating by examining the internal temperature of the hardware.
5. **Defaults**: Reset the system back to the system defaults to see whether the issues occur when the system is running in its default configuration.

Checks those steps to detect hardware issues.